# XML Document memory leak in Swift xcode

Tags: xml, swift, macos, memory-leaks

Hi I am new to the swift. I am writing one function for writing some data to xml document.

I am getting memory leak on line.

```
xmlDoc.XMLDataWithOptions(Int(NSXMLNodePrettyPrint) | Int(NSXMLDocumentIncludeContentTypeDeclaration))
```

Code snippet is as follows. I think there is some problem with xml object which is writing to file. when seen in instrument tool is pointing out to the line mentioned above. Because of this memory in program is growing after some time. :

```
    func WriteToFile(FileName: String,
                 bIsOffline: BooleanType,
                 StartTime: String,
                 EndTime: String,
                 ToolName: String,
                 Url: String,
                 WinTitle: String,
                 WindowID: Int,
                 ExeName: String,
                 CmdLine: String,
                 PID: Int)
{
    let HostName = NSHost.currentHost().name as String!
    let HostNameBase64 = ConvertStrToBase64(HostName.lowercaseString)
    //    if (NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(FileName)) {
    var StatObj = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(FileName, error: nil) as Dictionary!
    if (StatObj != nil) {
        let FileSize = StatObj["NSFileSize"] as NSNumber
        //var FileSize = FileSizeStr.toInt()
        var xmlDoc: NSXMLDocument!
        var RootNode: NSXMLElement
        if (FileSize.unsignedLongValue > 0) {
            let InputStr = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(FileName, isDirectory: false)
            xmlDoc = NSXMLDocument(contentsOfURL: InputStr!, options: Int(NSXMLDocumentTidyXML), error: nil)!
            RootNode = xmlDoc.rootElement() as NSXMLElement!
        } else {
            RootNode = NSXMLElement(name: "test")
            xmlDoc = NSXMLDocument(rootElement: RootNode)
            //            let Root = xmlDoc.rootElement()
            xmlDoc.characterEncoding = "UTF-8"
            xmlDoc.standalone = true
        }
            let WinInfoNode = NSXMLElement(name: "TEMP1")
            let TmpNode = NSXMLElement(name: "TEMP2", stringValue: StartTime)
            let TmpNode1 = NSXMLElement(name: "TEMP3", stringValue: EndTime)
            let TmpNode2 = NSXMLElement(name: "TEMP4", stringValue: HostNameBase64)
            WinInfoNode.addChild(TmpNode)
            WinInfoNode.addChild(TmpNode1)
            WinInfoNode.addChild(TmpNode2)
            RootNode.addChild(WinInfoNode)


        var DataToWrite: NSData = xmlDoc.XMLDataWithOptions(Int(NSXMLNodePrettyPrint) | Int(NSXMLDocumentIncludeContentTypeDeclaration))
        DataToWrite.writeToFile(FileName, atomically: true)
    }
    //    }
}
```

Any pointer of help will be appreciated.